# Which galaxy is closest to the center of the KBC void?

Tags: galaxy, galaxy-cluster

I was reading up on [Bootes void](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bo%C3%B6tes_void) and came across [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_cosmic_structures#List_of_largest_voids) of the largest voids in the visible universe, and apparently [the one we're in, the KBC void](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KBC_Void), is not only the biggest, but damned-near spherical.  The Wikipedia page says that the Milky Way is within a few hundred million light-years of the center of the KBC void, but I'm unable to find out what, if anything, is closest to the center.

Is this information available anywhere?  Does anyone know what's at the center of the KBC void?